# bash: How do I use a connection string to connect to a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, bash

Can I pass this string

```
mysql2://user1:rXbNgLjBHrdxYT@localhost/onebody?socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

to the mysql command inside bash, to make a connection?

If so, how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not literally. `mysql` CLI takes several options into which the string needs to be split (see `man mysql`).

Assuming "onebody" is the DB name, I guess it is:
`mysql --protocol=socket --socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --database=onebody --user=user1 --password=rXbNgLjBHrdxYT`.

> If you omit the password value following the --password or -p option
>              on the command line, mysql prompts for one.
>   Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. See Section 6.1.2.1, “End-User Guidelines for Password Security”. You can use an option file to avoid giving the password on the command line.